# A version of node.js that is multi-threaded?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, node.js

It's great that node.js is single threaded and follows an event model, but besides that it doesn't help me much. I have alot of cpu-bound tasks and I want each server request to be handled in a separate thread. Has anyone created a node.js fork that is multi-threaded yet?

I don't mean a module like [webworker-threads](https://www.npmjs.org/package/webworker-threads) where I need to wrap each one of my functions (which gets cumbersome for large projects). I mean, where each request comes in as a separate thread like most other web servers?

Comment: Make your CPU bound processes asynchronous, that is the way of Node.

Comment: Hasn't anyone come up with a way to multi-thread server post/get requests? I know I can multi-thread functions, but why hasn't express.js or node simply multi-threaded server calls?

Comment: @Halcyon the processes would still run on a single processor. I think the OP is asking "I have a N processors machine and Node just uses 1. How do I take advantage of all the processors available?"

Comment: No, I just have one processor. I want the server calls to be multi-threaded.

Comment: You can also write native add-ins that spin up threads or do whatever they want.  But there's still only one logical user thread inside Node that you deal with.  Changing that paradigm would break all kinds of things that people assume about how Node works.

Answer (score 4):

The common solution is to spawn several node.js threads (up to the number of CPU cores) using [build-in cluster module](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) or some third-party library.

Handling each request in a separate thread goes against node.js philosophy and nullifies all node.js advantages. There is no point in using node.js for such tasks, because there is a lot of other web servers which will do it much better.

On the other side, node.js offers you a more efficient way of handling web requests. So, instead of spawning a new thread for each request, node.js handles all requests in a single thread (or in a small pool of threads) using 100% of a single CPU core.

You should also keep in mind that node.js was designed for handling I/O bound tasks and can beat any other web server in it. But node.js is not so good at handling CPU bound tasks (e.g. calculations). So, if handling each request requires a lot of calculations then you picked the wrong tool.

Comment: Note that even "light-on-cpu" tasks such as parsing json, parsing an url or html templating  will throw node.js off and make it perform worse than average server so it's not just "heavy calculations".

Comment: my interest in node is end-to-end javascript. It's only limited by what the current features it has. I could care less about the philosophy. Soon there will be someone that will add this feature to it.

Answer (score 1):

consider using [IISNode](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode). From [hanselman's blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingAndRunningNodejsApplicationsWithinIISOnWindowsAreYouMad.aspx):

> Scalability on multi-core servers. Since node.exe is a single threaded
>   process, it only scales to one CPU core. The iisnode module allows
>   creation of multiple node.exe processes per application and load
>   balances the HTTP traffic between them, therefore enabling full
>   utilization of a server’s CPU capacity without requiring additional
>   infrastructure code from an application developer.

Comment: This is like node-cluster, not what the OP wants

Comment: @Esailija yes, may be not exactly what OP wants but something that I want. Voting +1 for useful link

Answer (score 1):

Probably yes, look e.g. for set of libraries

- [Popular threads modules - Node.js](https://nodejsmodules.org/tags/threads)

and this article (March 3, 2014)

- [JXcore – A Node.JS Distribution with Multi-threading](http://flippinawesome.org/2014/03/03/jxcore-a-node-js-distribution-with-multi-threading/)

Threads and [fibers](https://nodejsmodules.org/tags/fibers) were the question asked since the first Node.js days (at least what Google says seems to indicate that at least to me).

ES6 presumes that many concurrency requirements will be solved by [generators and promises](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/11/harmony-generators-and-promises-for-node-js-async-fun-and-profit) so from the future perspective designing your server side around concept of threads may become a problem in the long run.

Google's Dart (next gen web language) models concurrency also as separate entities (`isolate`) communicating through some simple message passing. See https://www.dartlang.org/docs/spec/latest/dart-language-specification.html chapter `Concurrency`.

On the contrary the usual model of `threads` expects some kind of `shared memory`. Which will not be available in the cluster mode and will not be available (at least soon) in the Dart as well.

So the request for threads may become a fatal architecture design problem from several points of view.

(I'm also used to "thinking threads", just noting that it may be wrong approach in the Node.js universe)

Comment: thanks for letting me know about jxcore, this is what I'm talking about..

Comment: @foreyez what a pitty. Googling out JXcore required the least effort and no knowledge. It comes up as 4th link when Googling for "node.js threads"..

Answer (score 0):

As xmojmr have mentioned, [JXcore](https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore/) can do this.

Did you see this article?: [How to turn your existing application into a multithreaded one with a few lines of code!](http://jxcore.com/how-to-create-multithreaded-nodejs-application-just-in-1-step/)

It runs an http server multi-threaded allowing each request to be handled by any of the threads.

Just run this code:

```
var http = require('http');
var cnt = 0;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write("Hello world! " + cnt++);
    res.end(0);
}).listen(2000, '127.0.0.1');
```

With the following command:

```
$ jx mt-keep:3 hello.js
```

And that's it. It runs 3 threads/instances inside of one process. JXcore chooses one of those 3 threads to process each request.